# The use of bidirectional binding of components in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a new learner of Vue.js and trying to implement the example ([example of currency filter](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisvfritz/1oqjojjx/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=1oqjojjx)) on the official guideline.

However, when implementing, I rename the property of the component (value) to (priceValue). After the change, the input box cannot format the value - it always shows '0' instead of the formatted value.

It is the only change I made. What is the problem?

```js
Vue.component('currency-input', {
  template: '\
    <div>\
      <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>\
      $\
      <input\
        ref="input"\
        v-bind:value="priceValue"\
        v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"\
        v-on:focus="selectAll"\
        v-on:blur="formatValue"\
      >\
    </div>\
  ',
  props: {
    priceValue: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.formatValue()
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue: function (value) {
      var result = currencyValidator.parse(value, this.priceValue)
      if (result.warning) {
        this.$refs.input.value = result.value
      }
      this.$emit('input', result.value)
    },
    formatValue: function () {
      // console log here always get 0 
      this.$refs.input.value = currencyValidator.format(this.priceValue)
    },
    selectAll: function (event) {
      setTimeout(function () {
       event.target.select()
      }, 0)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    price: 0,
    shipping: 0,
    handling: 0,
    discount: 0
  },
  computed: {
    total: function () {
      return ((
        this.price * 100 + 
        this.shipping * 100 + 
        this.handling * 100 - 
        this.discount * 100
      ) / 100).toFixed(2)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/chrisvfritz/5f0a639590d6e648933416f90ba7ae4e/raw/98739fb8ac6779cb2da11aaa9ab6032e52f3be00/currency-validator.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <currency-input 
    label="Price" 
    v-model="price"
  ></currency-input>
  <currency-input 
    label="Shipping" 
    v-model="shipping"
  ></currency-input>
  <currency-input 
    label="Handling" 
    v-model="handling"
  ></currency-input>
  <currency-input 
    label="Discount" 
    v-model="discount"
  ></currency-input>
  
  <p>Total: ${{ total }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [DOCS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

> For a component to work with `v-model`, it should (these can be
> configured in 2.2.0+):
>
> - accept a `value` prop
> - emit an `input` event with the new value

**This can be configured** sinse 2.2.x with a `model` options block:

```
Vue.component('currency-input', {
  model: {
    prop: 'propValue',
    // event: 'input'  - you can also customize event name, not needed in your case
  },
```

With this in place, your code will work again: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/j3a616a5/